# Why can't I record my microphone when audio is playing through my speakers?

Tags: audio, sound-card, microphone, audio-recording, audacity

I have a Conexant High Definition SmartAudio 221 device in my Compaq Presario CQ-60 211DX, and I want to record a Cyberacoustics headset through it via a standard 3.5mm jack. When I do this normally, in Audacity, it's wonderful, with stereo sound and great volume/quality. Unfortunately if I have any type of sound playing through the speakers at the same time, the recording audio gets extremely quiet/unsensitive and you can mostly hear garbled up noises that seem to be my voiced mixed with whatever is coming out of the speakers. I have experienced this also with the default sound recorded in Windows 7, and in Linux, so I believe it is a sound card issue.

My guess is I need to configure it so it will keep the signals straight, but I honestly have no idea how. Could, someone please point me in the right direction here?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I am assuming it is a notebook you're talking about? Did you check if the internal microphone gets disabled when you plug in the external one?

Comment: @tH0r Yes, it is a notebook. I don't know if the internal mic gets disabled or not. How would I check that? :)

Comment: @Miguel - Have you checked to make sure there's no noise cancellation active, in the drivers or sound control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps on the following webpage: [Compaq Support](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00833331&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=3866423) : the part about the default microphone may be interesting for you.

Or about directly muting the internal microphone: [Disable Int. Mic](http://www.ehow.com/how_8520966_disable-mic-compaq-presario-cq60.html)

If that doesn't help try this article about: [Driver Problems](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02032566&lc=en&cc=us&product=4121162) (and check if the steps above work now).